# Run Python webserver in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, python, chaquopy

I want to create AndroidTVApp which include Python webserver. I'm using python library Chaquopy. Simple python script like print HelloWorld works. I'm quite newbie but I think that I have to run webserver in Service class to run in background. It doesnt work. First of all I try to run Python in ShowWebsiteActivity.java but webview shows just blank page. So, this reason why I try to call and run Python script in Services. Python file works, I tried to run it on my pc but in AdnroidStudio doesnt. It raise this error - Cannot convert bytes object to java.lang.String. How can I run Python webserver in background?
Here is my code: 
**Java class**

```
public class ShowWebsiteActivity extends FragmentActivity {

WebView web;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    // CALLING SERVICES
    startService(new Intent(this,StartPythonWebServer.class)); 
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_website);
    web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    web.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/");

    textView = findViewById(R.id.DateTime);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    textView.setText(dateTime);

    final Button logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            web.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/menu");
        }
    });
}
```

**Service class**

```
public class StartPythonWebServer extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Python py = Python.getInstance();
    py.getModule("webserver").callAttr("start");

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

**Python**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, render_template, request
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder='static',
            template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/menu', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def menu():
    return render_template('menu.html')

@app.route('/content', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def content():
return render_template('index.html')

def start():
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot convert bytes object to java.lang.String

This is probably caused by [this issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/464): an incompatibility between the way click accesses stdout and the way Chaquopy redirects it to Logcat. We'll fix this in the next version of Chaquopy. Meanwhile, you can work around the problem by adding the following code to the start of your Python file:

```
import sys
for stream in [sys.stdout, sys.stderr]:
    def write_override(s, write_original=stream.write):
        if not isinstance(s, str):
            raise TypeError()
        return write_original(s)
    stream.write = write_override
```